# .NET not in feature list on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I am trying to install a program that needs .net 3.5, which is supposed to be build into windows 7 but when I try to activate it in the turn windows features on and off tool it is not there.  Downloading the installer just tells me I have to use the dialog I mentioned. I cant find anyone that has had the same problem. I have tried a bunch of tools and hot fixes that all can find no problems. Any other ideas

My system is Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

It should be listed right after "Media Features" but it is missing!

[image]

Comment: If that doesn't help.  Download a Windows 7 .ISO and add the feature that way.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with being the Enterprise version of W7???

Comment: @Ramhound your link has nothing to do with the fact it is missing in Windows Features list and cannot be installed manually.

Comment: @Moab - I realized that only after I fully read the link.  The feature must be manually added back into WinSxS in that case if its missing.

Comment: @Ramhound why not make an answer detailing how to do that?

Comment: Can you install 4.0?

Comment: I think you can get .NET 4 via the windows updater. It is backwards compatible with 3.5.

Comment: @jiggunjer, .net is not like that. a 3.5 app will not attempt to execute on 4.0. the only real exception to that is ASP.net handlers for IIS, which run their pipelines through .net 4, 2, or 1.1. if you run a 3.5 app through IIS, the pipelining is 2.0, but the assemblies loaded are 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install it by command line?

This should make the trick (disable and re-enable the feature):

> DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
>
> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /NoRestart

I found this solution [here](http://support.adminarsenal.com/entries/21033846-How-to-repair-re-install-NET-Framework-3-5).

**NOTE:** run command line as Administrator